# Arabic Language not getting Displayed if no English string concated at starting in android while making custom marquee

Tags: android, arabic, marquee

Arabic Language not getting Displayed if no English character concated at starting  in android while overridding TextView and Scrolling Text using android.widget.Scroller.

But If I am appending some English Character to Arabic String  it shows Arabic Properly

Below is ScrollTextView Code :-

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.widget.Scroller;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ScrollTextView extends TextView {
public int widthoftxt;

    public boolean isSmall;

    int refScrolLen=230;

    public static int screenwidth;

    public int widthofscreen;

    public String speed;
    // scrolling feature
    private Scroller mSlr;

    //Ticker Text Length
    public int strln;

    //Ticker Direction
    public String direc;

    // milliseconds for a round of scrolling
    private int mRndDuration = 10000;

    // the X offset when paused
    private int mXPaused = 0;

    // whether it's being paused
    private boolean mPaused = true;

    /*
    * constructor
    */
    public ScrollTextView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
    // customize the TextView
    setSingleLine();
    setEllipsize(null);
    setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
    }

    /*
    * constructor
    */
    public ScrollTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.textViewStyle);
    // customize the TextView
    setSingleLine();
    setEllipsize(null);
    setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
    }

    /*
    * constructor
    */
    public ScrollTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // customize the TextView
    setSingleLine();
    setEllipsize(null);
    setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
    }

    /**
    * begin to scroll the text from the original position
    */
    public void startScroll() {
    // begin from the very right side
    mXPaused = -1 * getWidth();
    // assume it's paused
    mPaused = true;
    resumeScroll();
    }

    /**
    * resume the scroll from the pausing point
    */
    public void resumeScroll() {

    if (!mPaused)
    return;

    // Do not know why it would not scroll sometimes
    // if setHorizontallyScrolling is called in constructor.
    setHorizontallyScrolling(true);

    // use LinearInterpolator for steady scrolling
    mSlr = new Scroller(this.getContext(), new LinearInterpolator());
    setScroller(mSlr);

    int scrollingLen = calculateScrollingLen();
    int distance = scrollingLen - (getWidth() + mXPaused);
    int duration = (new Double(mRndDuration * distance * 1.00000/ scrollingLen)).intValue();
    int dur=0;
    int sp=3000;

        if(speed.equalsIgnoreCase("slow")){
            sp=5000;
        }
        else if(speed.equalsIgnoreCase("medium")){
            sp=3000;
        }
        else if(speed.equalsIgnoreCase("fast")){
            sp=1000;
        }

    if(direc.equalsIgnoreCase("rtl")){

        int temp=scrollingLen/refScrolLen;
        dur=temp*sp;
        setVisibility(VISIBLE); 
        //For LEFT
        mSlr.startScroll(mXPaused, 0, scrollingLen, 0,dur);
    }
    if(direc.equalsIgnoreCase("ltr")){
        int temp=(scrollingLen + screenwidth)/refScrolLen;
        dur=temp*sp;
        setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    //For RIGHT
        mSlr.startScroll(scrollingLen, 0, -(scrollingLen + screenwidth), 0, dur);
    }

    /*
     * Parameters
    startX  Starting horizontal scroll offset in pixels. Positive numbers will scroll the content to the left. 
    startY  Starting vertical scroll offset in pixels. Positive numbers will scroll the content up. 
    dx  Horizontal distance to travel. Positive numbers will scroll the content to the left. 
    dy  Vertical distance to travel. Positive numbers will scroll the content up. 
    duration  Duration of the scroll in milliseconds. 
     */
    mPaused = false;
    }

    /**
    * calculate the scrolling length of the text in pixel
    *
    * @return the scrolling length in pixels
    */
    private int calculateScrollingLen() {
    TextPaint tp = getPaint();
    Rect rect = new Rect();
    String strTxt = getText().toString();
    Log.e("LENGTH   OF TEXT ",strTxt.length()+strTxt);
    tp.getTextBounds(strTxt, 0, strTxt.length(), rect);
    int scrollingLen = rect.width() + getWidth();
    rect = null;
    return scrollingLen;
    }

    /**
    * pause scrolling the text
    */
    public void pauseScroll() {
    if (null == mSlr)
    return;

    if (mPaused)
    return;

    mPaused = true;

    // abortAnimation sets the current X to be the final X,
    // and sets isFinished to be true
    // so current position shall be saved
    mXPaused = mSlr.getCurrX();

    mSlr.abortAnimation();
    }

    @Override
    /*
    * override the computeScroll to restart scrolling when finished so as that
    * the text is scrolled forever
    */
    public void computeScroll() {
    super.computeScroll();

    if (null == mSlr) return;

    if (mSlr.isFinished() && (!mPaused)) {
    this.startScroll();
    }
    }

    public int getRndDuration() {
    return mRndDuration;
    }

    public void setRndDuration(int duration) {
    this.mRndDuration = duration;
    }

    public boolean isPaused() {
    return mPaused;
    }

   }
```

Below is the Main Activity class implementing ScrollTextView-

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ArabicActivity extends Activity {

    public int woftxt;
    public int flag = 0;
     private TextView tv;
    public ScrollTextView scrollRSSText;


    private Animation inFromRightAnimation() {
        Animation inFromRight = new TranslateAnimation(
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
        inFromRight.setDuration(500);
        inFromRight.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        return inFromRight;
    }

    private int getScreenWidth() {
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        int actual_scr_width = dm.widthPixels;
        return actual_scr_width;
    }

    private String stringPadding(String str) {
        flag = 0;
        String strTxt = new String();
        strTxt = str;
        int fco = 0;
        int swidth = getScreenWidth();
        Rect rect = new Rect();
        while (rect.width() < swidth) {

            TextPaint tp = new TextPaint();
            rect = new Rect();
            tp.getTextBounds(strTxt, 0, strTxt.length(), rect);
            strTxt = strTxt + "$";
            fco++;
        }
        if (fco > 1) {
            flag = 1;
        }
        TextPaint tp = new TextPaint();
        rect = new Rect();
        tp.getTextBounds(strTxt, 0, strTxt.length(), rect);
        woftxt = rect.width();
        strTxt = strTxt.substring(0, strTxt.indexOf("$"));

        for (int i = 0; i < fco; i++) {
            strTxt = strTxt + " ";
        }
        // strTxt=strTxt+"!!!!!!!!!!";
        return strTxt;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_arabic);

try{
        // Step 3
        // tt.setText(z.TickerText);
        String Tdirection = "right";
        String Tfont = "40";

        String Tspeed = "50";
        String Tfontsize = "40";
        String Tfontcolor =  "#FFFFFF";
        String Tbackcolor = "#8B0000";
        String Tstr = "مرحبا بكم في دبي-";
        String speedset = null;
        int tickerSpeed = Integer.parseInt(Tspeed);
        if (tickerSpeed == 50) {
            speedset = "fast";
        } else if (tickerSpeed == 90) {
            speedset = "medium";
        } else if (tickerSpeed == 150) {
            speedset = "slow";
        }

        ScrollTextView.screenwidth = getScreenWidth();
        ScrollTextView scrollText = new ScrollTextView(this);
        Tstr = stringPadding(Tstr);
        scrollText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        scrollText.widthoftxt = woftxt;
        scrollText.widthofscreen = getScreenWidth();
        scrollText.setHeight((int)50);
        if (Tdirection.equalsIgnoreCase("right")) {
            scrollText.direc = "rtl";
        } else {
            scrollText.direc = "ltr";
        }

        scrollText.strln = Tstr.length();
        scrollText.setX(0);
        scrollText.setY(0);
        scrollText.setTextSize(Float.parseFloat(Tfontsize));
        scrollText.setText("ad"+"مرحبا بكم في دبي"); // if English string added than its working
        //scrollText.setText("مرحبا بكم في دبي");  //No English string added so it is not working
                scrollText.speed = speedset;
        scrollText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(Tfontcolor));
        scrollText.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(Tbackcolor));
        scrollText.startScroll();
        scrollText.setTextSize(Float.parseFloat(Tfontsize));
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);
        rl.addView(scrollText); 

}
catch(Exception er){
    Log.e("Errror",er.getMessage());
}
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.arabic, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: so was my ans work it your side dude

Comment: have you solved this problem..if yes then please post the solution as I am facing same problem with wheel widget http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23607684/kankans-wheel-is-not-setting-arabic-text-in-real-device-while-working-fine-in-e

Answer (score 0):

Try this take refrence findviewbyid in your activity and then in java class set this text view it work my side

```
filename_downloading_text.setText("حبا بكم في دبي"");
 filename_downloading_text.setSingleLine(true);
 filename_downloading_text.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
 filename_downloading_text.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
 filename_downloading_text.setFreezesText(true);
 filename_downloading_text.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
 filename_downloading_text.setFocusable(true);
 filename_downloading_text.setSelected(true);
```

**best of luck :)**

Comment: <TextView
            android:id="@+id/filename_downloading_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#868686" />

Comment: On this text view which i send u xml code, i set in java class with taking findviewby id refrence and this is  working fine at my side